# Specifying R to take one argument at a time when passing multiple arguments using '...'

Tags: r, function

I am a novice in R required by my superior to do things a certain way. I am interested in determining values of descriptive statistics *setup count* and *heavy-dominance setup count*. *Setup count* basically counts the number of setups found within a location, while *heavy-dominance setup count* counts the number of setups that has dominance values of *x* population ≥ 50% within the said location. This is how I would normally calculate said statistics:

```
##Normal Approach
#Sample Data 1
v <- c(53, 2, 97) #let vector "v" represent Location 1
w <- c(7, 16, 31, 44, 16) #let vector "w" represent Location 2

#Setup Count
sc_v <- length(v)
sc_w <- length(w)
sc <- c(sc_v, sc_w)
sc

#Heavy-Dominance Setup Count
hd_v <- length(which(v >= 50))
hd_w <- length(which(w >= 50))
hd <- c(hd_v, hd_w)
hd
```

I am tasked with developing a function that can both determine said statistical values from raw data and concatenate the outputs into a single vector. Here are the working functions I developed:

```
#Setup Count (2 vectors at a time only)
setup.count <- function(x, y){
  a <- length(x)
  b <- length(y)
  d <- c(a, b)
  d
}

#Heavy-Dominance Setup Count (2 vectors at a time only)
heavy.dominance <- function(x, y){
  a <- length(which(x >= 50))
  b <- length(which(y >= 50))
  d <- c(a, b)
  d
}

y <- setup.count(v, w)
y
z <- heavy.dominance(v, w)
z
```

Suppose there are more than two locations:

```
#Sample Data 2
v <- c(53, 2, 97)
w <- c(7, 16, 31, 44, 16)
x <- c(45, 22, 96, 74) #let vector "x" represent the additional Location 3
```

How can I specify R to take one argument at a time when passing multiple arguments using '...'? Here are the failed attempts to revise the abovementioned functions, to give an idea:

```
##Attempt 1
#Setup Count (incorrect v1)
setup.count <- function(x, ...){
  data <- list(...)
  a <- length(x)
  b <- length(data) #will return the number of locations other than x, not the separate number of setups within each of these locations
  d <- c(a, b)
  d
}

#Heavy-Dominance Setup Count (incorrect v1)
heavy.dominance <- function(x, ...){
  data <- list(...)
  a <- length(which(x >= 50))
  b <- length(which(data >= 50)) #will return the error "'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"
  d <- c(a, b)
  d
}

y <- setup.count(v, w, x)
y
z <- heavy.dominance(v, w, x)
z

##Attempt 2
#Setup Count (incorrect v2)
setup.count <- function(x, ...){
  data <- list(...)
  a <- length(x)
  b <- length(unlist(data)) #will return the total number of setups in all locations other than x, not as separate values
  d <- c(a, b)
  d
}

#Heavy-Dominance Setup Count (incorrect v2)
heavy.dominance <- function(x, ...){
  data <- list(...)
  a <- length(which(x >= 50))
  b <- length(which(unlist(data) >= 50)) #will return the total number of setups with dominance ≥ 50% in all locations other than x, not as separate values
  d <- c(a, b)
  d
}

y <- setup.count(v, w, x)
y
z <- heavy.dominance(v, w, x)
z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just `list()` elements in the ellipsis. Use `sapply()` to loop over the list elements. Add a `type=` argument to have one function for both purposes, and a `thresh=` argument.

```
setup.fun <- function(..., type=c('count', 'dominance'), thresh=50) {
  x <- list(...)
  type <- match.arg(type)
  if (type == 'count') sapply(x, length)
  else sapply(x, function(x) length(which(x >= thresh)))
}

setup.fun(v, w, x)
# [1] 3 5 4
setup.fun(v, w, x, type='count')
# [1] 3 5 4
setup.fun(v, w, x, type='dominance')
# [1] 2 0 2
setup.fun(v, w, x, type='d')
# [1] 2 0 2
setup.fun(v, w, x, v)
# [1] 3 5 4 3
setup.fun(v)
# [1] 3
setup.fun(v, w, x, type='dominance', thresh=40)
# [1] 2 1 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. I was going to ask first why the first setup.fun(v, w, x, v) and second setup.fun(v, w, x, v) in the example you provided gave outputs of different lengths despite being exactly the same, but I suppose the first setup.fun(v, w, x, v) contains a typographical error and should just be setup.fun(v, w, x).

Comment: @MikiG. Indeed just a copy-paste mistake. Edited, thanks for the pointer.